# Unable to store uploaded image using PHP and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am learning Laravel and attempting to create a webpage to upload Picture albums. I have read up on the laravel documentation on verification and each field is being verified. However, upon clicking submit, the image does not post to the store method.

The route is set in web.php

```
Route::get('/albums/create', 'AlbumsController@create')->name("album-create");
Route::post('/albums/store', 'AlbumsController@store')->name("album-store");
```

The form code is shown below:

```
<div class="container">

  <h2> Create New Album </h2>

    <form method="post" action="{{ route('album-store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token(@csrf) }}">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name: ">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Description</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="description"  placeholder="Enter description">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Cover Image</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="cover_image" id="cover-image" placeholder="cover-image">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

and finally we have the controller function below:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
  $this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required',
    'description' => 'required',
    'cover-image' => 'required'
  ]);

  $filenameWithExtension = $request->file('cover-image')->getClientOriginalName();

      $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExtension, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

      $extension = $request->file('cover-image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
// time stamping the images uplaoded
      $filenameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;

// saving the file to the disk (can be found in 'storage/app/public/album_covers..')
      $request->file('cover-image')->storeAs('public/album_covers', $filenameToStore);

  $album = new Album();
  $album->name = $request->input('name');
  $album->description = $request->input('description');
  $album->cover_image = $filenameToStore;
  $album->save();
```

When I click submit on the form after filling the fields, I still receive the error "Cover-image" is required. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHCHk.png)

Comment: The name of the input is `cover_image`, not `cover-image`. The input name gets passed in, not the id.

Answer (score 1):

the field in html is `cover_image`
while the validation is `cover-image`

```html
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="cover-image">Cover Image</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="cover-image" id="cover-image" placeholder="cover-image">
        </div>
```

*The labels `for` attribute is set to target the field with id="name", not related to the issue but i thought you need to look in the html file it needs some attention.*

Comment: So does that mean that the validation is actually done using the field "name"? I thought it was the "id"

Answer (score 1):

your cover image input field name is cover_image and you take the value and validate it as cover-image write form group input filed like bellow

`<div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Cover Image</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="cover-image" id="cover-image" placeholder="cover-image">
        </div`